# Pandas is too slow to handle FIFO inventory requirements. How can I optimize the performance of this code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Note: packing is an inventory table, and orders is an order demand table, that is to say, I need to use the Item_number of Orders to match the Item_number of packing, and count which Box_numbers in packing can make an order
For example: when Item_number = 'A' in the orders table, I need to use Item_number to match the Item_number corresponding to packing to see if Inventory_quantity is in stock

Case 1: Item_number = 'A' in the first row of the orders table, Order_quantity needs to be 100, then you need to go to packing to find Item_number = 'A', you can see that Box_number = 2, Inventory_quantity = 1000, then Inventory_quantity is assigned to A = 100, Inventory_quantity left 900

Situation 2: Item_number ='B' in the second line of the orders table, Order_quantity needs to be 100, then you need to go to packing to find Item_number ='B', you can see that Inventory_quantity is equal to B and there are two rows of data, respectively Box_number =2, Inventory_quantity= 50 and Box_number = 3, Inventory_quantity = 50, then Inventory_quantity is assigned to B = 100, and Inventory_quantity is left with 0.

Situation 3: Item_number = 'B' in the third line of the orders table, and Order_quantity needs 50, then you need to go to packing to find Item_number = 'B'. At this time, you can see that Inventory_quantity has two rows of data, but Inventory_quantity has just been assigned to B , the inventory is insufficient, so Insufficient inventory quantity is displayed: ' + order_qty

Situation 4: Item_number = 'C' in the fourth line of the orders table, and Order_quantity needs to be 100, then you need to go to packing to find Item_number = 'C'. At this time, it is found that the packing does not have data equal to C, so it shows not in the packing list

I tried to write such a piece of pandas code, but when the orders and packing are 1W lines respectively, the processing speed will be super slow, and even no results will appear.

I hope someone can help me optimize the speed of this code, thank you very much!

```
import pandas as pd
orders = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item_number': {0: 'A', 1: 'B',2: 'B',3: 'C'},
    'Order_number': {0: 10001, 1: 10002, 2: 10003, 3: 10004}, 
    'Order_quantity': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 50, 3: 100}
})

packing = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item_number': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B'}, 
    'Box_number': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 
    'Inventory_quantity': {0: 1000, 1: 50, 2: 50}
})
orders = pd.concat([orders] *1500)
packing = pd.concat([packing ] *1500)
```

```
def match_orders_packing(orders, packing):
    grouped_packing = packing.groupby('Item_number')
    result = []
    for idx, row in orders.iterrows():
        order_num = row['Order_number']
        part_num = row['Item_number']
        order_qty = row['Order_quantity']
        
        if part_num in grouped_packing.groups:
            part_packing = grouped_packing.get_group(part_num)
        else:
            result.append((part_num, order_num, None, None, 'not in the packing list'))
            continue
        
        for pidx, prow in part_packing.iterrows():
            box_num = prow['Box_number']
            pack_qty = prow['Inventory_quantity']

            if order_qty == pack_qty:
                result.append((part_num, order_num, box_num, pack_qty, None))
                packing.at[pidx, 'Inventory_quantity'] = 0
                order_qty = 0
                break

            elif order_qty < pack_qty:
                result.append((part_num, order_num, box_num, order_qty, None))
                packing.at[pidx, 'Inventory_quantity'] = pack_qty - order_qty
                order_qty = 0
                break

            else:
                if pack_qty == 0:
                    continue
                result.append((part_num, order_num, box_num, pack_qty, None))
                packing.at[pidx, 'Inventory_quantity'] = 0
                order_qty -= pack_qty
        
        if order_qty > 0:
            result.append((part_num, order_num, None, None,'Insufficient inventory quantity：' + str(order_qty)))
    
    return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Item_number', 'Order_number', 'Box_number', 'Inventory_quantity', 'Remark'])

result = match_orders_packing(orders, packing)
print(packing)
result
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `get_group()` constructs a dataframe, which is somewhat expensive. I think you do not need the groupby at all, as it is only used to filter the `packing` data for the current item number. I would rather use the `query()` method instead, making the code clearer and also allowing you to include the condition `Inventory_quantity > 0`, so that you do not iterate over irrelevant rows.

Thus, the following version of your code should be faster:

```py
def match_orders_packing(orders, packing):
    
    packing_items = set(packing.Item_number)
    result = []
    
    for idx, row in orders.iterrows():
        order_num = row['Order_number']
        part_num = row['Item_number']
        order_qty = row['Order_quantity']
        
        if part_num not in packing_items:
            result.append((part_num, order_num, None, None, 'not in the packing list'))
            continue
        
        for pidx, prow in packing.query("Item_number == @part_num and Inventory_quantity > 0").iterrows():
            box_num = prow['Box_number']
            pack_qty = prow['Inventory_quantity']

            if order_qty <= pack_qty:
                result.append((part_num, order_num, box_num, order_qty, None))
                packing.at[pidx, 'Inventory_quantity'] = pack_qty - order_qty
                order_qty = 0
                break
            else:
                result.append((part_num, order_num, box_num, pack_qty, None))
                packing.at[pidx, 'Inventory_quantity'] = 0
                order_qty -= pack_qty
        
        if order_qty > 0:
            result.append((part_num, order_num, None, None,'Insufficient inventory quantity：' + str(order_qty)))
    
    return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Item_number', 'Order_number', 'Box_number', 'Inventory_quantity', 'Remark'])
```

Comment: There's one thing I don't quite understand,
When the orders are repeated 3000 times, it seems that my original code will get the result faster.

orders = pd. concat([orders] *3000)
packing = pd. concat([packing] *1)

But when orders and packing are repeated 3000 times at the same time, the code you gave me will get the result faster at this time. why is this

orders = pd. concat([orders] *3000)
packing = pd. concat([packing] *3000)

Comment: Well, I did focus on the inner loop, over the packing data, because I saw a way to speed it up for the given example data. If the packing dataframe is much smaller than the other one, this does of course change the priorities.